# Not getting values in formCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used form as follows:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Complete_Evaluation","PP")" method="POST" id="frmObservationScoring">
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnaccountid" value="@ViewBag.AccountID" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnObservationID" value="@ViewBag.ObservationID" />
    <button onclick="return CompleteObservation();" class="buttoncss">Complete</button>
</form>
```

On Controller page i am trying to use it as:

```
public ActionResult Complete_Evaluation(FormCollection fc)
{
    int AccountID = Request.Form["hdnaccountid"];

    int ObservationID = fc.GetValues("hdnObservationID"); 

    return view();
}

AccountID = Request.Form["hdnaccountid"];
```

is the one method by which i am trying to get the value and

```
ObservationID = fc.GetValues("hdnObservationID");
```

By both the ways i am getting null values.

i have made sure from my code that hiddenfields do contain proper values.

Then how can i get the values from form collection???

Comment: are you sure ViewBag.AccountID and ViewBag.ObservationID have initial values? try to replace it with just hardcoded value, 'value="213"'

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the `id` for identifying your fields in the form, you should use the `name` since that attribute is used to identify the field in forms:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnaccountid" value="@ViewBag.AccountID" />
```

Comment: @Messi: Need more help?

Answer (score 4):

You should use name instead of id.

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Complete_Evaluation","PP")" method="POST" id="frmObservationScoring">
<input type="hidden" name="hdnaccountid" value="@ViewBag.AccountID" />
<input type="hidden" name="hdnObservationID" value="@ViewBag.ObservationID" />
<button onclick="return CompleteObservation();" class="buttoncss">Complete</button>
</form>
```

hdnaccountid and hdnObservationID should be name of inputs.